# How to see Monitor temporary cell with ParallelSubmit?

Tags: front-end, parallelization, monitoring

I have a function to load large files into a `"HSQL(Standalone)"` database for processing that uses `Monitor` to update the interface on the progress and status of the upload.

```
loadBigFile[t_Integer?Positive, steps_Integer?Positive] :=
 Module[{stepProgress = 0},
  Monitor[
   While[stepProgress < steps,
    (* Read batch and load to db *)
    Pause[t];
    stepProgress += 1
    ],
   Column[{StringRiffle[ToString /@ {stepProgress, steps}, " of "],
     ProgressIndicator[stepProgress, {0, steps}]},
    Alignment -> Center]
   ];
  stepProgress
  ]
```

`loadBigFile` is just to demonstrate the issue.

```
loadBigFile[1, 10]
(* 10 *)
```

[image]

This process takes 30+ minutes to load each file. I would like to concurrently load these files to reduce the wait time by using `ParallelSubmit`.

```
k = LaunchKernels[2];
DistributeDefinitions[loadBigFile];
{f1, f2} = {ParallelSubmit[loadBigFile[1, 5]], ParallelSubmit[loadBigFile[1, 9]]}
```

[image]

When I execute `WaitAll` the `EvaluationObject`s do run concurrently. However, instead of a monitor temporary cell for each of them I get a front end error from each kernel they are running on.

```
WaitAll[{f1, f2}]
CloseKernels[k];
```

[image]

```
(* {5, 9} *)
```

> FrontEndObject::notavail: A front end is not available; certain operations require a front end.

How do I get the monitor temporary cells to show in the notebook for each `EvaluationObject` running?  Or is there another method I should use for concurrent execution with `Monitor`?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitoring+parallel

Comment: You'll have to put the monitoring outside of the parallel kernels.

Comment: @Karsten7. That did it. Not certain if I should post an answer here or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the link in the comment above I have devised a solution included here for `ParallelSubmit` specific searches.

`Monitor` can not be used so I make a `progress` function that will assist with the visual status update.

```
progress[current_, total_] :=
 Column[{StringRiffle[ToString /@ {current, total}, " of "],
   ProgressIndicator[current, {0, total}]},
  Alignment -> Center]
```

I use a `status` `Association` to hold the status updates as it makes the code more readable than using a list as with other solutions.  The `loadBigFile` function has to change slightly.

```
loadBigFile[t_Integer?Positive, steps_Integer?Positive] :=
 Module[{stepProgress = 0},
  status[[Key[$KernelID]]] = <|
    "File" -> "File " <> ToString@RandomInteger[100],
    "Monitor" -> progress[stepProgress, steps]
    |>;
  While[stepProgress < steps,
   (* Read batch and load to db *)
   Pause[t];
   stepProgress += 1;

   (* Update status *)
   status[[Key[$KernelID], "Monitor"]] = progress[stepProgress, steps];
   ];

  status[[Key[$KernelID], "File"]] = status[[Key[$KernelID], "File"]] <> " done.";
  stepProgress
  ]
```

The `Key`s of the `Association` are the `$KernelID` and each has a `"File"` and `"Monitor"` key. `loadBigFile` updates these as it progresses.

```
k = LaunchKernels[2];

status = Association @@ 
     ParallelTable[$KernelID -> <|"File" -> "", "Monitor" -> ""|>, {i, $KernelCount}]
(* <|43 -> <|"File" -> "", "Monitor" -> ""|>, 42 -> <|"File" -> "", "Monitor" -> ""|>|> *)
```

Distribute the definitions and variables

```
DistributeDefinitions[progress, loadBigFile];
SetSharedVariable[status];
```

`ParallelSubmit` the jobs.

```
{f1, f2} = {ParallelSubmit[loadBigFile[1, 5]], ParallelSubmit[loadBigFile[1, 9]]}
```

[image]

`PrintTemporary` with `Dynamic` is used instead of `Monitor`. This accesses the `status` association to display.

```
PrintTemporary[
  Dynamic[Row[
    Riffle[Column[#, Alignment -> Center] & /@ 
      Query[Values, Values]@Select[#"Monitor" =!= "" &]@status, Spacer[5]]]]];
WaitAll[{f1, f2}]
```

[image]

Both have status displayed and updated concurrently.

Clean up.

```
UnsetShared[progress, loadBigFile, status];
CloseKernels[k];
```

Hope this helps.