# Monitor ParallelMap (again) - how to predict the number of function calls efficiently?

Tags: monitoring, parallelization

I am currently implementing a function to let me monitor the progress of a computation running in parallel (similar to the answers in [Monitor doesn't work with ParallelTable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1548)). The goal is to have a function that can be wrapped around any parallel computation, to show the progress of it (e.g.: `parallelProgress[ParallelTable[...]]`). Since something like that is nigh to impossible to implement for "any parallel computation", I settled for now to implementing it for the four big ones: `ParallelTable`, `ParallelMap`, `ParallelDo`, `ParallelSum`. After figuring out the basics, the implementation for `ParallelTable`, `ParallelDo`, `ParallelSum` were rather straightforward (and almost identical). `ParallelMap` however is giving me some problems, mainly due to the *`levelspec`* parameter. The problem is to figure out the total number of function calls automatically and quick.
For example in

```
ParallelMap[f,Evaluate[Range[10]]]
```

the number of times f is called is easily calculated using `Length`. For *`levelspec`* different from `{1}` you can calculate it using `Dimensions`, as long as you have a rectangular array. However, in

```
ParallelMap[f,Evaluate[Range[Range[10]]],{2}]
```

the answer is not so straightforward. Here is what i did so far:

```
SetAttributes[parallelProgress, {HoldAll}]
parallelProgress[expr_] :=
 ...
 Module[{...,max,...},
  ...
  Count[holdexpr,
    HoldPattern[
      ParallelMap[
        Alternatives[Function[par_, body_, attr_: {}], Function[body_],f_Symbol], mapExpr_, levelSpec_: {1}, 
        OptionsPattern[ParallelMap]
    ] /; (
      dim = Dimensions[mapExpr]; 
      If[MatchQ[levelSpec, n_Integer /; (n >= 0 && n <= Length[dim])], 
        max += Times @@ Flatten[Table[dim[[i]], {i, 1, levelSpec}]], 
      If[MatchQ[levelSpec, {n_Integer} /; (n >= 0 && n <= Length[dim])], 
        max += Times @@ dim[[levelSpec[[1]]]], 
      If[MatchQ[levelSpec, {m_Integer,n_Integer} /; (n >= 0 && m >= 0 && m <= n && n <= Length[dim])], 
        max += Times @@ dim[[levelSpec[[1]] ;; levelSpec[[2]]]], 
      Map[max++&, mapExpr, levelSpec]]]]; True
    )],
    \[Infinity]];
 ...
 ]
```

I use patternmatching so that cases like `parallelProgress[{ParallelMap[...],ParallelMap[...]}]` can also be handled. For all `ParallelMap` instances found I first try to calculate the number of calls via `Dimensions`. If that is not possible, I resort to `Map[max++, mapExpr, levelSpec]`, which in my tests worked actually better than `Length[Level[mapExpr, levelSpec]]`. However, this strikes me as being unnecessarily verbose. Is there a way to compute the number of function calls more easily and/or faster?

### Edit:

Fixed a typo in the code.

Regarding the use of `Length[Level[...]]`:
I compared this method with my simple `Map[n++&,...]`:

```
Array[List, {100, 20, 1000}];
{2};
AbsoluteTiming[Module[{n = 0}, Map[n++ &, %%, %]; n]]
AbsoluteTiming[Length[Level[%%%, %%]]]
%[[1]]/%%[[1]]
```

With a variety of arrays and level specifications. While i didn't do a comprehensive study, my observations were as follows:

- With deeper levels `Level` is slightly faster (the lowest ratio I ever got from the code above was ~0.6)
- With shallow levels and large lists `Map` is *much* faster (the highest ratio I ever got from the code above was ~100 **!!**)

but most importantly:

- `Level` seemed to crash (run out of memory, I guess) for smaller Lists, compared to `Map`.

All in all this leads me to prefer `Map[n++ &,...]` over `Length[Level[...]]` even though the latter is more concise (which with Mathematica usually means faster).

Comment: It seems that `Length@Level[mapSecondArgument, mapLevelspec]` from your `ParallelMap[f, mapSecondArgument, mapLevelspec]` call would give you the number of elements to be mapped over, and therefore the number of function calls (unless the function to be mapped is recursive, in which case all bets are off...). Perhaps I am missing a more complex case though.

Comment: Be aware of the potential performance impact: [How to make the ProgressIndicator for ParallelDo more efficient](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123703/18476)

Answer (score 4):

I not certain why you seem not to like [`Length`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Length.html)`@`[`Level`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Level.html).  With this and [`Monitor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Monitor.html) you can construct a `monitorParallelMap` that appears to achieve your goal.

```
ClearAll[monitorParallelMap];
monitorParallelMap[foo_, expr_, levelSpec_: {1}, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[ParallelMap]] :=
 Module[{res, exprCount, progress = 0},
  LaunchKernels[];
  SetSharedVariable[progress];
  exprCount = Length@Level[expr, levelSpec];
  res =
   Monitor[
    ParallelMap[(Pause[.25]; progress++; foo[#]) &, expr, levelSpec, opts],
    Column[{ToString@progress <> " of " <> ToString@exprCount, 
      ProgressIndicator[progress, {0, exprCount}]}, 
     Alignment -> Center]
    ];
  UnsetShared [progress];
  res
  ]
```

`monitorParallelMap` gets the number of calls with `Lenght@Level` and uses a [`SetSharedVariable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetSharedVariable.html) across the kernels to update the progress. `Pause[.25];` was added for the demonstration to slow things down enough so we can see what is happening. `Monitor` displays the progress as the [`ParallelMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelMap.html) progresses.

Then

```
monitorParallelMap[f, Range[Range[10]], {2}]
```

displays an updating [`ProgressIndicator`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProgressIndicator.html) as it evaluates

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and then the results of the `ParallelMap`.

> ```
> {{f[1]}, 
>  {f[1], f[2]}, 
>  {f[1], f[2], f[3]}, 
>  {f[1], f[2], f[3], f[4]}, 
>  {f[1], f[2], f[3], f[4], f[5]}, 
>  {f[1], f[2], f[3], f[4], f[5], f[6]}, 
>  {f[1], f[2], f[3], f[4], f[5], f[6], f[7]}, 
>  {f[1], f[2], f[3], f[4], f[5], f[6], f[7], f[8]}, 
>  {f[1], f[2], f[3], f[4], f[5], f[6], f[7], f[8], f[9]}, 
>  {f[1], f[2], f[3], f[4], f[5], f[6], f[7], f[8], f[9], f[10]}}
> ```

For heavier parallel processing with monitoring you may find this answer ([19542](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118692/19542)) interesting.

Hope this helps.