# Matrix Vector multiplication for very big matrices (>>RAM)

Tags: list-manipulation, numerics, linear-algebra, streams

**Problem**

Suppose a matrix-vector product of the form $M\vec{v}$ should be calculated where the amount of storage needed to store $M$ is noticeably larger than the available RAM on a machine. What is the fastest way to perform such an operation?

**Slow solution approach**

Since Mathematica takes care of such problems by the provision of `InputStream` object I thought of using them and implemented a version where the matrix $M$ is given as (very long) stream. I `Dot` it row-wise with the vector $\vec{v}$ and collect the results as final result vector

```
Table[Dot[NextStreamEntries[matrixStr, VectorLength], v], {ii,VectorLength}].
```

Here `matrixStr` is the matrix as an `InputStream` and `VectorLength` is the `Length`of the vector $\vec{v}$. By the way, I use a `Table` to do exactly the same thing `VectorLength` times. This seems weird but I did not find another fast (!) solution.

The performance of this is a catastrophy. Using the `` RuntimeTools`Profile `` I found that the performance is worse because of this method

```
NextStreamEntries[stream_, count_] := BinaryReadList[stream, "Real64", count];
```

with which I travel through the rows of the matrix.

**On request: What does the matrix store and where does it come from?**

The matrix comes from outside MMA since performance matters. A C++ routine writes it to disk as a binary file and I bit by bit read in in from MMA with `BinaryReadList`. The matrix elements are quantum mechanical expectation values (needed in context of the iterated equations of motion approach to describe non-equilibrium physics) with very few elements equal to zero.

Comment: `ParallelMap[#.v &, m]`

Comment: @Edmund Thanks for your answer. Can you elaborate on it in detail? The problem I see is that the stream is not guaranteed to be read in the correct order which will lead to a wrong result. Maybe I did not get your point.

Comment: can you tell me how many elements has he matrix?

Comment: @Alucard It depends on many different factors. A typical example is a quadratic matrix of $70k$ entries of floating numbers that leads to $64*(70000^2) \mathrm{bit} \approx 39.2 \mathrm{GB}$. And this doesn't fit into (at least) my memory.

Comment: Whenever people claim that a given matrix would not fit into memory, I use to ask: How many _nonzero_ entries does the matrix have? Often, matrices of this size have their origin in a partial differential operator and can be better represented by a `SparseArray`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Right. Usually, this is the case. I heavily rely on `SparseArray` in my own code. For reference: My matrix has about 1% of  elements equal to zero.

Comment: @pbx Okay. That's quite likely too many nonzeros to be exploited. Still, I am curious: Where does this matrix come from? How is it produced? Do you need many matrix-vector multiplications or only a few? How expensive is the creation of the matrix rows compared to saving them on HD and even piping them through string expressions? A binary format for storage should be _much_ faster since the bottleneck here should be the bandwidth of your mass storage...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks for your interest. I edited my post and answered most of your questions in the original post now. The matrix creation is extremely expensive and almost impossible in MMA. My mass storage device is an NVMe SSD (Samsung 960) which comes in quite handy here :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use [`ParallelTable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelMap.html) and other functions from the [Parallel Computation Setup & Configuration](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ParallelComputationSetupAndConfiguration.html) guide.

With

```
m = LowerTriangularize@ConstantArray[1, {10, 10}];
v = ConstantArray[1, 10];
MatrixForm /@ {m, v}
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

This `m` and `v` is selected to demonstrate that order is preserved.

Then create the stream.

```
stream = StringToStream@ExportString[m, "Table"];
```

and setup for parallel evaluation

```
LaunchKernels[];
SetSharedVariable[stream];
sig = ConstantArray[Real, Length@v];
b = ParallelTable[Quiet@Read[stream, sig].v, {Length@v}];
UnsetShared[stream];
MatrixForm@b
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Clean-up.

```
Close[stream]
```

As you can see the order is preserved as the stream is shared over the kernels. You can use `Number` instead of `Real` if you have integer data.

I am getting a warning that the stream is not open but it is and the code does execute in parallel.  I will look into that.  You can silence the warning with `Quiet@Read`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is highly interesting. Up to now I did not even know about `SetSharedVariable` which does the magic here undoubtedly. +1 and of course an answer acceptance. Thanks. :)

Comment: @pbx Just added an update so that the `Read` signature is not created on each read. Should be ever so slightly faster. May result in a big difference in your case.

Comment: @pbx Since your matrix is so huge you can look into modifying this answer ([19542](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153389/19542)) for `ParallelTable` so that you can track the progress as it evaluates.