# Monitor progress of each kernel within ParallelTable

Tags: parallelization, monitoring

I am generating a table using `ParallelTable` and for each table entry a `Do` loop is required. I want to monitor the progress of both the overall table and the progress of each `Do` loop.

I have an example code below where I am able monitor the progress of the table construction.

```
   LaunchKernels[];
   iCount = 0;
   SetSharedVariable[iCount];

   Monitor[
   table = ParallelTable[
     iCount++;
     ans = 0;
     Do[
      ans += j;
      , {j, 1, i}];
     {ans}
     , {i, {10^1, 10^2, 10^3, 10^4, 10^5, 10^6}}];
  , iCount];
```

How can I modify this to also monitor the progress of `j` on each subkernal in the `Do` loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the [`ParallelSubmit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelSubmit.html) pattern detailed in this answer ([19542](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118692/19542)).

With

```
progress[current_, total_] := 
 Column[{
   StringRiffle[ToString /@ {current, total}, " of "], 
   ProgressIndicator[current, {0, total}]
  }, 
  Alignment -> Center]
```

and

```
k = LaunchKernels[];
status = Association @@ 
  ParallelTable[$KernelID -> <|"Label" -> "", "Monitor" -> ""|>, {i, $KernelCount}]
```

> ```
> <|4 -> <|"Label" -> "", "Monitor" -> ""|>, 
>   3 -> <|"Label" -> "", "Monitor" -> ""|>, 
>   2 -> <|"Label" -> "", "Monitor" -> ""|>, 
>   1 -> <|"Label" -> "", "Monitor" -> ""|>|>
> ```

Then define the worker function that also updates the status.

```
doWork[jvalue_Integer] :=
 Module[{ans = 0, stepProgress = 0},
  status[[Key[$KernelID]]] = <|
    "Label" -> "j Value: " <> ToString@jvalue, 
    "Monitor" -> progress[stepProgress, jvalue]|>;
  Do[
   stepProgress++;
   ans += j;
   status[[Key[$KernelID], "Monitor"]] = progress[stepProgress, jvalue];,
   {j, 1, jvalue}];
  status[[Key[$KernelID], "Label"]] = status[[Key[$KernelID], "Label"]] <> "  is done.";
  {ans}
  ]
```

Distribute definitions

```
DistributeDefinitions[progress, doWork];
SetSharedVariable[status];
```

and setup the jobs

```
jobs =
 Table[
  ParallelSubmit[{i}, doWork[i]],
  {i, {10^1, 10^2, 10^3, 10^4, 10^5, 10^6}}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Evaluate jobs in parallel and wile tracking progress.

```
PrintTemporary[
  Dynamic[Row[
    Riffle[Column[#, Alignment -> Center] & /@ 
      Query[Values, Values]@Select[#"Monitor" =!= "" &]@status, 
     Spacer[5]]]]];
WaitAll[jobs]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Clean up

```
UnsetShared[progress, doWork, status];
CloseKernels[k];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is great, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Developed from my `monitorParallelMap` function ([19542](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153389/19542)).  Same concepts but slightly adjusted from [`ParallelMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelMap.html) to [`ParallelTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelTable.html).

```
ClearAll[monitorParallelTable];
monitorParallelTable[expr_, iter__List, opts : OptionsPattern[ParallelTable]] :=
 Module[{res, iterCount, progress = 0},
  LaunchKernels[];
  SetSharedVariable[progress];
  iterCount =
   Times @@
    Map[If[VectorQ[#, NumericQ], Length@*Range @@ #, Length@Flatten@#] &]@
     Map[Rest, {iter}];
  res = Monitor[
    ParallelTable[
     (
      progress++;
      expr
      ),
     iter, opts],
    Column[{ToString@progress <> " of " <> ToString@iterCount, 
      ProgressIndicator[progress, {0, iterCount}]}, 
     Alignment -> Center]];
  UnsetShared[progress];
  res]
```

Then

```
r1 =
  monitorParallelTable[i j k,
   {i, 5},
   {j, 10, 100, 10},
   {k, 10^{1, 2, 3, 4}}
   ];
```

displays an updating [`ProgressIndicator`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProgressIndicator.html)as it evaluates

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

With a longer version of the OP calculation.

```
r2 = monitorParallelTable[
   Sum[i, {i, j}],
   {j, 10^Range@500},
   Method -> "CoarsestGrained"
   ];
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

`monitorParallelTable` takes the same options as `ParallelTable`.  The calculation of the number of iterations is not robust.  It only calculates correctly if the iterators are independent of one another. For example, `..., {i, 10}, {j, i}, ...` will calculate 10 instead of 55. `iterCount`'s calculation can be changed to `Length@Flatten@Table[1, iter]` for a more robust (an more costly) iteration calculation solution.

For heavier parallel processing with monitoring you may find this answer ([19542](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118692/19542)) interesting.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, @Edmund this is a useful way to monitor a `ParallelTable` however, I am specifically interested in monitoring the `Do` loop on each kernel within the `ParallelTable`.